# Understanding the SHA1-UPDATE and SHA1-FINAL functions

Tags: swift, openssl, sha1

Swift 5, iOS 14

Trying to understand someone else code an I need some help because but I not sure I understand SHA1_UPDATE SHA1_FINAL functions clearly.

This is doing what--

```
private func computeHash() -> Data {
 let identifierData = getDeviceIdentifier()
 var ctx = SHA_CTX()
 SHA1_Init(&ctx)
```

// it creates a sha-1 hash of identifier bytes and puts them into &CTX memory

```
 let identifierBytes: [UInt8] = .init(identifierData)
 SHA1_Update(&ctx, identifierBytes, identifierData.count)
```

// and then it creates sha-1 hash of opaqueBytes and then adds them to? &CTX memory?

```
 let opaqueBytes: [UInt8] = .init(opaqueData!)
 SHA1_Update(&ctx, opaqueBytes, opaqueData!.count)
```

// does it again, creates sha-1 hash of bundleBytes and then adds them to &CTX memory

```
 let bundleBytes: [UInt8] = .init(bundleIdData!)
 SHA1_Update(&ctx, bundleBytes, bundleIdData!.count)
```

// And then uses data to create another?

```
  var hash: [UInt8] = .init(repeating: 0, count: 20)
  SHA1_Final(&hash, &ctx)
  return Data(bytes: hash, count: 20)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// it creates a sha-1 hash of identifier bytes and puts them into &CTX memory
```

This is where you're going wrong. It is not creating a SHA-1 hash of the bytes. It is updating the SHA context (state) with the data. No final hash has been computed yet.

```
SHA1_Final(&hash, &ctx)
```

At this point, the hash is computed based on the current SHA context, which accumulates *all* the data.

It is true that in SHA-1, there is internal state preserved in the final hash, and this allows for a class of attacks called [Length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). But this is a weakness in the algorithm, not a design goal.

Comment: ok, but I want to reproduce this with openssl, I can do a sha-1 with this? openssl dgst -sha1 -hex  but how does that relate to  the final SHA-1

Comment: Sorry your saying it simply copying the bytes into the &CTX memory location, and then when it has all of them computing the hash at the end?

Comment: No, not copying. Updating the context based on those bytes. When you call FINAL, there will be additional padding added as well. All the SHA algorithms work on fixed-sized blocks.

Comment: I don't understand the question about openssl. The commandline openssl doesn't have a mode for performing partial hashes (the C API does, but not the commandline). You need to collect all your data and hash it together.

Comment: Does SHA1_Update add padding?

Comment: No. If it did that it would matter how many times you call update. The whole point of the update function is that you can call it with data of arbitrary length. Your example code happens to be making calls to update with individual components of some larger data structure, but a very common usage is to call update periodically with uniform blocks read from a file or network. The underlying point is that you can call update 100 times with 10 bytes or one time with 1000 bytes and it'll give you exactly the same answer.